How to set the Visual Studio C# Comment Out approach
I'm using VS Community 2022 v17.10.5.  Just recently, when I comment out c# code in a Blazor component (.razor), it is using "@* @" instead of "//".  It uses "//" in my .cs files. I get why it would use "@ *@" in the markup, but it's always used "//" in the @code until something happened recently.  How can I get it to use "//" when in c# code?  Thanks.

What are you seeing in your C# code?  /* */  is used to wrap large blocks of comments, and // is used for line-by-line.  I do not believe you can change this in VS.

My guess is your code block is not bracketed correctly, and so it thinks that it is markup.

VS puts // at the start of each C# line when I comment out one or more lines, except in one .razor file where I am having the problem.  @Bennyboy, your thought seems very plausible.  I've looked over the markup and code and am not seeing anything amiss.  And VS is not signaling an error when I build.  If I remove the opening { at the start of the code section, the next statement raises an error (as expected).  Curiously, if I add a 2nd } at the end of the code section, no error is thrown.  I'll have to keep looking based on your suggestion.

Can you provide razor code and screenshots to help us reproduce the problem? Will the problem occur in the latest VS?

I've tried to reproduce the problem, without success.  Since it seems to be happening only in one Blazor component, I'm not sure what's driving it.  Also, I just upgraded to the latest release (v17.11.4).  The problem is still there.  Finally, I've still not found any bracketing problems as suggested by Bennyboy.

Does copying the code into a new razor file solve the problem? Maybe there is problem with the encoding of the file.

Someone suggested that I copy the code from the problematic component into a new one to see if the problem copied too.  Great suggestion.  A straight copy did replicate the problem, so I copied the component piece-by-piece.  Ultimately, that showed that the problem was due to an "else" line in which I included a comment after the "else" (i.e. "else @*  Comment  @"). Somehow in all the coding I've done, I've never come across that problem.  In any case, removing the "@  Comment  *@" fixed the problem. So, @Bennyboy was right.

Glad to know your problem is solved! See Can I answer my own question?  Just a reminder :)
